# JetBrains Fleet: Run & Debug

Tags: java, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

Just started working with JetBrains' new IDE Fleet and so far been loving the experience. Just have one issue with the platform. I am trying to run  debug on a simple java file but the option is greyed out:

[image]

Tried setting up a config file but that didn't work. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `Debug` not `Degub`.

Comment: I corrected that and it did nothing